# Como criar uma classe que contenha uma lista de objetos de uma classe pai?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, lista, objetos

Preciso criar uma classe pessoa que terá os atributos (nome, idade) e uma classe grupo que conterá uma lista de objetos da classe pessoa. Entretanto não sei como fazer a segunda classe... Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
```

Como eu poderia criar a classe "grupo"?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa trabalhar com herança neste seu caso é mais facil criar uma classe Grupo contendo uma lista de pessoas e adicionando val

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade


class Grupo:
    def __init__(self):
      self.list_pessoas = []
      pass
    
    def addPessoa(self,obj_pessoa):
      assert isinstance(obj_pessoa,Pessoa), "Tem que ser uma classe do tipo pessoa"
      self.list_pessoas.append(obj_pessoa)
    
    def printPessoas(self):
      for p in self.list_pessoas:
        print(f'{p.nome} --> {p.idade}')

#Crio cada pessoa
pessoa1 = Pessoa('joao',12)
pessoa2 = Pessoa('maria',15)
pessoa3 = Pessoa('pedro',18)

grupo = Grupo()
#Adiciono a lista dentro da classe grupo
grupo.addPessoa(pessoa1)
grupo.addPessoa(pessoa2)
grupo.addPessoa(pessoa3)

#Printo todas as pessoas na tela
grupo.printPessoas()

# joao --> 12
# maria --> 15
# pedro --> 18
```